# Need help writing and reading a file with PHP

Tags: php, atom-editor

So for an assignment, I have to create a form where users can post ride shares so other people can see and join their ride. I'm doing this by writing the form to a file data.txt, and reading the file to display all the rides on a board. My only problem is when I get the contents of data.txt, it's all combined together. I need to be able to display each ride separately. How would I go about doing this?

Here is my code so far:
The writing:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])
              && isset($_POST['email'])
              && isset($_POST['date'])
              && isset($_POST['destination'])
              && isset($_POST['msg'])) {
          $name = $_POST['name'];
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $date = $_POST['date'];
          $destination = $_POST['destination'];
          $msg = $_POST['msg'];

          //TODO the file write here VV, use 'a' instead of 'w' too ADD to the file instead of REWRITING IT.
          $arr = [$name,$email,$date,$destination,$msg];

          $write = json_encode($arr);
          $file = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
          fwrite($file, $write);
          fclose($file);
      }
```

And the reading:

```
  $path = 'data.txt';
          $handle = fopen($path, 'r');
          $contents = fread($handle, filesize($path));
          echo $contents;
          fclose($handle);

          $newarr = [json_decode($contents)];

          foreach($newarr as $stuff)
          {
            echo $stuff[0];
          }
```

And the output is something like:

```
["Simon Long","example@gmail.com","2109-01-01T01:01","canada","this is a message"] Simon Long
```

Let's say there are multiple postings in there, it would just print them all together. I need a way to separate postings so I can display them nicely on the board.

Answer (score 1):

Use a multidimensional array.

```
$arr = [
    "Simon Long","example@gmail.com","2109-01-01T01:01","canada","this is a message",
    "John Doe","john@gmail.com","2109-01-01T01:01","canada","this is a message",
    "Jane Doe","jane@gmail.com","2109-01-01T01:01","canada","this is a message"
];
```

Then you when you add to it just append to the final array and replace the whole file.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
$decoded = json_decode($contents);
$decoded[] = [$name,$email,$date,$destination,$msg];
file_put_contents($path, json_encode($decoded)); //replace the entire file.
```

Also just as a side note. `isset` accepts multiple arguments so you don't need to use it as you are. You can do this:

`if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['destination'] ...)`

It's also a good idea to sanitise any input from the user.

`$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

Comment: Hey, your code is giving me an error, says file_put_contents expects at least 2 parameters, what should I do?

Comment: Ahh yes. This is what happens when I code without testing :P The second argument should be the content and first should be the path. I would encourage you to read the documentation when you get errors. But I will fix my answer.